# HTTP how to live streaming video using Parse

Tags: video, parse-platform, video-streaming, html5-video, live-streaming

I want to provide a live streaming video service similar to twitch using parse.com, how can I do that?
There is no answer in the whole web so far related to parse.com + live video streaming.
I want to avoid using flash player, but as last resource is fine.

Comment: How are you even thinking about doing this with parse? I am curious

Answer (score 4):

Parse would be a bad choice to use as a content hosting provider. You would be constantly pressing your storage cap, not to mention the limitations on the bandwidth usage.

Use Parse as a general-purpose backend for user authentication and app data, then host the video content on another service such as AWS and reference those resources using cloud code web hooks.

To help get you started:

[AWS Content Streaming](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/)

[Parse Cloud Code Web Hooks](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-cloud-code-webhooks/)

Comment: thanks for your answer! forget for a minute the storage cap and bandwidth, is it impossible to live video streaming using parse? is that what you are telling me?

Comment: my question is if it is possible to live streaming video using parse.com?

Comment: Correct, It is impossible to do "live" or real-time streaming using Parse. Parse would allow you to upload videos and have other users stream/download them, but not in real-time like Twitch.

Comment: You would have to look into using another service such as AWS, PubNub, etc either as a replacement to Parse or in addition to it for offering complementary services.